# How to detect duplicate artifacts in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I know that artifactory uses checksum based storage and will only store one copy of an artifact even if I upload multiple identical ones under different names.

As I have many projects with version-anonymous but probably identical jars, I would like to know if there is any way of getting artifactory to tell me which artifacts are referenced under multiple ids.

Answer (score 4):

While Artifactory has no existing feature that provides this info, it is actually quite easy to achieve with a small script that utilizes Artifactory's [REST-API](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API).

You can for example, write a tree walker (using the [Folder Info resource](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#Artifactory%27sRESTAPI-FolderInfo)) that maps checksums to files (file checksum can be obtained using the [File Info resource](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#Artifactory%27sRESTAPI-FileInfo)).

Or if you use the Pro version of Artifactory, you can retrieve a list of all artifacts within a repository using the [File List resource](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#Artifactory%27sRESTAPI-FileList)

Answer (score 1):

Here's SQL to run against the PostGreSQL database. I haven't tried it with any other database.

```
select sha1_actual, node_name, node_path, repo, *
from nodes
where sha1_actual in 
(
    select sha1_actual 
    from nodes
    where node_type != 0
    group by sha1_actual
    having count(1) > 1
)
order by sha1_actual
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# search in artifactory, lists duplicates angelos@unix.gr
#

search=$1

if [ "X$search" == "X" ]
then
    echo "$0 <search item>"
    exit 1
else
    search=`echo $search |sed -e 's/ /\%20/gi' `
    search="*${search}*"
fi

USER=`whoami`
PASS=${PASS:-somepass}
CREDS=${USER}:${PASS}
ARTIFACTORY=https://artifactory.somesite.com/artifactory

curl -s -u ${CREDS} -o search.txt ${ARTIFACTORY}/api/search/artifact\?name=${search}

echo "List of all uris is in search.txt"
echo "All instances of $search follow"
echo "---------------------------------"
grep $search search.txt | grep -v pom | awk '{ print $3}'  | xargs -i  basename {} | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```